# How to print a sectors' tree with a function?

Tags: php, recursive-datastructures

I've got a function that give the childs of a father sector. So I need to print each one and their childs, and so on.

```
class sector {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $father_sector;
    
    public function bringChilds() : array {
        return BD::findChilds();
    }
}
```

The function returns an array of objects or just empty.
I need to print the list of sectors.
I tried using a while, but i do not understand where to stop.

Something like:

```
print($sector)
foreach($sector->bringChilds() as $child) {
    print($child)
    foreach($child->bringChilds() as $childer) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Dude, you did not give any update?

Answer (score 0):

You just need recursive calls to a function that takes `$sector` as an argument.

```
<?php


function printSectors($sector){
   print($sector);
   foreach($sector->bringChilds() as $child) {
     printSectors($child); // call for child recursively again
   }
}

printSectors($sector);
```